Calculating heading of vehicle with IMU in random starting orientation
I can’t get my head around this problem.
I’m doing this in C but I need help with quaternions.
I have an IMU (3axis gyro & accel) in a box. This box can be positioned in any orientation, then fixed to a car.
After it turns on, the orientation it’s fixed relative to the car will not change.
I must get the heading of the car (twisting around the ground plane, I don’t mind that it’s relative to nothing).
I currently have an accurate quaternion orientation in the IMU frame and can get the gravity vector on start up at rest.
What should I be doing here?
I’ve tried reading up on various ways to manipulate quaternions but can’t get it just yet.

What is the initial orientation of the car?

You can invert quaternions. So you can take the inverse of the initial quaternion, and multiply each value with this inverse. That way all rotations should be relative to the identity quaternion.

If you need calibration "on the fly" than search for surround view in the cars. They do this job. Only way to get "heading"  is to analyze motion of car (and mounted IMU).

@JonasH Interesting. After this, how do I get a heading or angle that only changes when the car moves around it's yaw axis?

Multiply whatever vector is "forward" with the quaternion to get a rotated vector, then project this to the XY plane (i.e. remove the Z) and get the heading with Atan2.
